# gotoAndPlay works, but Stops rather than plays? - as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The following as3 is inside a movie clip of instance name 'counter_int' on root level and the targeted movieclip instance name 'win_message' lives separately on root level too.

Prior to using the listener/function and if statement method below, this worked perfectly and the 'win_message' movicelip played fine WHEN entering a new frame within 'counter_int' which contained the same as3, minus the listener and if statement.

All still works except i.e. it still communicates with targeted movicelip due to the fact, it, the 'win_message' movieclip stops on frame 2, instead of continuing to play. There are no stop(); commands in the targeted movieclip other than on frame 1 btw.

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, success);

function success(ev : Event) : void

{
    if (linked_total.text == (5).toString () )
    { 
       Object(root).win_message.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Apologies if I'm not great at explaining my problem!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because you are using the `gotoAndPlay()` inside the listener of the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event, so it's called repeatedly until the condition is false.

Although, It's a bad manner to do like that, you can instead use any punctual action (button click, text field change, ...) which you know that will be executed just when your user need that.

If you still need, for any other cause, to use the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event listener, you should ensure the your condition will be true just once ( or at least you will call `gotoAndPlay()` once ), then you can call the `gotoAndPlay()`, by using a `Boolean` var for example :

```
var first_run:Boolean = true;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, success);
function success(ev:Event) : void
{
    // when first_run is false, we are sure that even if linked_total.text still equals to "5"
    // this condition will always be false
    if (int(linked_total.text) == 5 && first_run)
    {       
        first_run = false;
        MovieClip(root).win_message.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```

You can also remove the event listener when the condition is true for the first time, but in this case, I don't know why you will use the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` event listener !

```
function success(ev:Event) : void
{
    if (int(linked_total.text) == 5)
    {       
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, success);
        MovieClip(root).win_message.gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
}
```

... There are really many manners to accomplish what you want with avoiding the behavior that you got.

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks akmozo. Forgive my cluelessness. I quickly tried pasting both of those as3 pieces into (instead of my current as3) and no luck. I might need more 'hand-holding' to be honest!!!

Comment: @spumker Sorry, I did a mistake in my code, it's `int(linked_total.text) == 5` instead of `int(linked_total.text) = 5` ;) Sorry again. Try it and tell me what you get.